# Verifying searched text displayed is in a single line

Tags: ruby, selenium

How can I test whether a sentence (combination of four or five words) is displayed in  a single line?

I have to search with a name or some other fields. After search results are displayed, I should test whether the displayed text is a single line. For example, the code below is used to verify the search result link:

> //ol[contains(@class,'search results')]/li[contains(@class,'mod result') and contains(@class,'XXXXXX')]//a[contains(@href,'trk=XXXXXX')]

Comment: Do you mean in the HTML or in the actual display of the line? If it's the later, you can't. A single line could be defined in the HTML, but the user's browser could have a tiny window open forcing the line to wrap. Or, the CSS, or JavaScript could cause the line to wrap after the HTML has been loaded, in which case you'd have to sniff out dynamically occurring changes to the page.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), but the following [java](/questions/tagged/java) approach should work in any language.

Assuming that your "sentence" is entirely contained in one element, you could find all occurrences with something like:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='your sentence']"))
```

Then simply test for the size of the array.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that a single or multiple lines will be contained within a single DOM element, you could use the vertical component of the element size to check for the multiple line condition.

```
webElement.getSize()
```